# WPF - Create a floating animated clickable control (image or...)

Tags: c#, wpf, floating, animated, suspend

[image]
I want create a **floating animated clickable**  control like a helium balloon that moves sometimes to right or left too in my WPF application.

> The helium balloons likes go up! but also they moves right or left if
>   we tap on them or by wind.
>
> In advance cases, sometimes they turn to right or left

..................................[image][image][image]..................................

So i searched the web but i didn't find any usefull sample project or library or styles.

- How i can create style and animation in WPF to show an image or
  control buoyant or suspended in air.?
- Have you any suggestions to implement this idea simply...?

**Edit:**

- What is your suggestion for a **random and infinite smooth turns to right and left**. for example 51degrees to left then 163degree to right and.... i want keep my balloon in my window and **often top of the window**.

---

**Edit:**

I created an animation base on these answers but more complex by manipulating them and adding multiple parallel animation on balloon image and its container. ;)
Thanks all...

Now my primary result is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `DoubleAnimation` and a `RotateTransform` like @Ega mentioned. To answer your "random and infinite" turns to right and left, here's how you could do it (it's very basic but does the job).

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var direction = -1;

        while (true)
        {
            var percent = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            direction *= -1; // Direction changes every iteration
            var rotation = (int)((percent / 100d) * 45 * direction); // Max 45 degree rotation
            var duration = (int)(750 * (percent / 100d)); // Max 750ms rotation

            var da = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                To = rotation,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration)),
                AutoReverse = true // makes the balloon come back to its original position
            };

            var rt = new RotateTransform();
            Balloon.RenderTransform = rt; // Your balloon object
            rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);

            await Task.Delay(duration * 2); // Waiting for animation to finish, not blocking the UI thread
        }
    }
```

**edit** for .NET 3.5

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(this.AnimateBalloon);
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void AnimateBalloon()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var direction = -1;

        while (true)
        {
            var percent = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            direction *= -1; // Direction changes every iteration
            var rotation = (int)((percent / 100d) * 45 * direction); // Max 45 degree rotation
            var duration = (int)(750 * (percent / 100d)); // Max 750ms rotation

            Balloon.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                (Action)(() =>
                {
                    var da = new DoubleAnimation
                    {
                        To = rotation,
                        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration)),
                        AutoReverse = true // makes the balloon come back to its original position
                    };

                    var rt = new RotateTransform();
                    Balloon.RenderTransform = rt; // Your balloon object
                    rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);
                }));

            Thread.Sleep(duration * 2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use .net 3.5. May you change your code to support .net 3.5? The Task and... is not supported....

Answer (score 1):

[Farseer Physics Engine](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home) for C# will allow you to create a real world simulation. You can control gravity, inertia, force and even other physical stuff.

```
    World world = new World(new Vector2(0f, 9.82f));
    //We create a body object and make it dynamic (movable)
    Body myBody = world.CreateBody();
    myBody.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;

    //We create a circle shape with a radius of 0.5 meters
    CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape(0.5f);

    //We fix the body and shape together using a Fixture object
    Fixture fixture = myBody.CreateFixture(circleShape);
```

For this scenario you may need to create a world with less gravity and objects will fly. You can apply force from either side of the object to move it.

Answer (score 0):

in C# `DoubleAnimation`is a powerful Class Support Animation inside  `System.Windows.Media.Animation;` NameSpace so this class have some Methods and Properties let me to tell you it

```
DoubleAnimation ANobj = new DoubleAnimation();//make object from DoubleAnimation
ANobj.From=0 //the 0 is point you want to star animation
ANobj.To=270//the end pont of moving 
// that values  is dependent on your self as you want
ANobj.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)); //specify the duration of moving 
ANobj.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;//RepeatBehavior as you want
```

also use `RotateTransform` class to Rotate C# Componets in WPF

```
RotateTransform RTobj=new RotateTransform();//make object from RotateTransform
RTobj.CenterX = 277;//X point of your Element(Componet)
RTobj.CenterY = 245;//Y point of your Element(Componet)
RTobj.Angle = 360;//angle between 
RTobj.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty,ANobj);
```

also after doing that configures set this obj to `RenderTransform` property from your Element like it

```
yourElementName.RenderTransform=RTobj
```

if you want read more at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Animation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about `System.Windows.Media.Animation`

Comment: do you have this in XAML form as well?

Comment: yes but my project is kurdish manual clock it was animated like manual clock

Comment: @Ezzat, your code is a good idea and i used it in my app but what is your suggestion for a random and infinite smooth turns to right and left. for example 51degrees to left then 163degree to right and.... i want keep my balloon in my window and often top of it!

Comment: ANobj.From=51;
ANobj.To=163; 
ANobj.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;  RTobj.CenterX = 106

Answer (score 0):

Here is one I did in high school. Probably very outdated now but just for interest sake.

```
//the animation thread
        System.Threading.Thread thr;

        thr = new System.Threading.Thread(annimate);
        thr.Start();
```

the animation method

```
 void annimate()
    {     
        try
        {       
            double angleToAnimateTo = 20;
            double CurrentAngle = 0;
            bool increment = false;

            while (IsAnimating)
            {
                if (increment)
                    CurrentAngle++;
                else
                    CurrentAngle--;

                if (CurrentAngle == angleToAnimateTo )
                    increment = false;

                if (CurrentAngle == (angleToAnimateTo * -1))
                    increment = true;


                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    this.imgBallon.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(CurrentAngle);
                }));

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
```

imgBalloon is a simple image in wpf. Here is the xaml..

```
<Image x:Name="imgBallon" 
        Source="/img/balloon_blue.png" Width="50"> </Image>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonny, but when we use `Animations features of WPF`, we have `Softer Moves`!

Comment: @RAM, yes certainly :) Like i said, this was done a couple years ago when i was still in school. Its just for interest sakes :)

Answer (score 0):

May This help You Here,I take polygon and One image to left to right you can set by Your choice :)

```
<Window x:Class="Animation.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="XAML Animation - Spinning Stars" Height="300" Width="355"
        >
        <Grid Name="myGrid">
          <Canvas Margin="15,18,18,26" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="50" Name="canvas1">
            <!-- Invisible element just to host composite transform -->
            <Polygon
                Name ="mypolygon1"

                Stroke="Blue"

                StrokeThickness="1.0"

                Points="176.5,50 189.2,155.003 286.485,113.5 201.9,177 286.485,240.5 

        189.2,198.997 176.5,304 163.8,198.997 66.5148,240.5 151.1,177 

        66.5148,113.5 163.8,155.003">

              <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                  <RotateTransform x:Name="xformRotate" CenterX="176" CenterY="145" />
                  <TranslateTransform x:Name="xformTranslate" X ="-50" Y="-50" />
                  <ScaleTransform x:Name ="xformScale" ScaleX=".25" ScaleY=".25" />
                </TransformGroup>
                </Polygon.RenderTransform>

              <Polygon.Fill>

                  <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue">
                      <!--<ColorAnimation From="Yellow" To="Blue" Duration="7"

                        RepeatCount="500" AutoReverse="True"/>-->

                  </SolidColorBrush>

                </Polygon.Fill>
                <Polygon.Triggers>
                  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Polygon.Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                      <BeginStoryboard>
                      <Storyboard>
                        <!-- RotateTransform angle from 0 to 360, repeated -->
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xformRotate"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                         From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:01"
                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xformTranslate"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                         From="1" To="750" Duration="0:0:14"
                                         AutoReverse ="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                      </Storyboard>
                      </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                  </EventTrigger>
                  </Polygon.Triggers>

              </Polygon>
            <Polygon
                Name ="mypolygon2"

                Stroke="Red"

                StrokeThickness="1.0"

                Points="176.5,50 189.2,155.003 286.485,113.5 201.9,177 286.485,240.5 

        189.2,198.997 176.5,304 163.8,198.997 66.5148,240.5 151.1,177 

        66.5148,113.5 163.8,155.003">

              <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                  <RotateTransform x:Name="xformRotateIt"   CenterX="176" CenterY="145"  />
                  <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".25" ScaleY=".25" />
                  <TranslateTransform  x:Name="xformTranslateIt" X="0" Y="100" />
                </TransformGroup>
              </Polygon.RenderTransform>

              <Polygon.Fill>

                <SolidColorBrush x:Name ="mybrush" Color="Red" />
              </Polygon.Fill>
              <Polygon.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Polygon.Loaded">
                  <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                      <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryBoard" Completed="OnCompletedAnimation">
                        <!-- RotateTransform angle from 0 to 360, repeated -->
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xformRotateIt"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                         From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:01"
                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="xformTranslateIt"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                         From="1" To="100" Duration="0:0:14"
                                         AutoReverse ="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="mybrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="Red" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:7" 
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                      </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                  </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
              </Polygon.Triggers>

            </Polygon>


            <Image Margin="75,61,0,119" Name="image1" Source="Images\KENNY.bmp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="72">
              <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                  <RotateTransform x:Name="KennyRotateIt"   CenterX="50" CenterY="50" Angle="45"  />
                  <ScaleTransform x:Name="KennyScaleIt" ScaleX=".75" ScaleY=".75" />
                  <TranslateTransform  x:Name="KennyTranslateIt" X="0" Y="100" />
                </TransformGroup>
              </Image.RenderTransform>
              <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                  <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                      <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryBoard1" Completed="OnCompletedAnimation">
                        <!-- RotateTransform angle from 0 to 360, repeated -->
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="KennyRotateIt"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                         From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:01"
                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                             Storyboard.TargetName="KennyTranslateIt"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                             Duration="0:0:10" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">

                          <!-- These KeyTime properties are specified as TimeSpan values 
                     which are in the form of "hours:minutes:seconds". -->
                          <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="10" KeyTime="0:0:3" />
                          <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="100" KeyTime="0:0:5" />
                          <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="200" KeyTime="0:0:10" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <!-- DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="KennyTranslateIt"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                         From="-50" To="100" Duration="0:0:14"
                                         AutoReverse ="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" / -->
                      </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                  </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
              </Image.Triggers>
            </Image>
          </Canvas>
      </Grid>

            </Window>
```